# failed to open stream:startup.php - Opencart hosting Issue

Tags: php, opencart, web-hosting

I'm facing a big trouble after host opencart which is my first experience though. 
I transferred all files and folders to my host and edited config file and admin/config file. but when I type the URL I'm receiving

```
 Warning: require_once(/home/XXX/public_html/oc1551/system/startup.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/XXX/public_html/index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/XXX/public_html/oc1551/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/XXX/public_html/index.php on line 17
```

The above path `/home/XXX/public_html/oc1551/` which is incorrect and I already changed it to correct path after confirm from my hosting. I changed all entries in both config and admin/config files. `But I'm still receiving this error and it still include wrong path as there was earlier.`

when I contact the hosting support they are saying this is syntax error but I think this is not. I didn't change any paths in scripts. Only edited config files.

I checked over the internet but couldn't find a solution yet. Any help or clue would be appreciated. If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew My question is different and it relates to opencart as I explained already.

Answer (score 1):

You should check following:

1. File "/home/XXX/public_html/oc1551/system/startup.php" exists and has permissions not less than 640.
2. All directories in the path "/home/XXX/public_html/oc1551/system/" have permissions not less than 755.

Comment: thanks for your support. The issue is given path in error such as "/home/XXX/public_html/oc1551/system" isn't correct. I already added correct path to both config files. But error display as wrong path.

Comment: If web-server don't have permissions to access file or any folder in path to file, you get same error ("No such file or directory.."). The problem with permissions is not corrected by config files. You moved all files into new folders. So I advised you check permissions.

Comment: I checked permission. they are correct. But  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks man for your support. I solved the issue it isn't  relates to the permission though.